# What happens in an EPS false positive?

Tags: electrical, power-steering

I was wondering, what will happen if for whatever reason the electric power steering system gets a false positive, worst case scenario - at high speed?

I suppose the same question holds valid for hydraulic power steering systems but as I'm not much into oils it's easier for me to see how and EPS would malfunction.

Electronics fail, lets say some transistor failed or an op amp gave a false reading, whatever the case might be, wouldn't that cause the motor to steer the vehicle out of it's path and if at high speed - most probably cause an accident?

Comment: I am not aware of any fully electric power steering systems for on-road vehicles.  What is currently available should more properly be called electrically assisted power steering.  There is still a mechanical linkage that can still be operated, albeit at higher input force, even if the electric parts fail.

Comment: @jwh20 I mean if they fail in a way such that the electric motor keeps "providing assist" or turning the wheel even if there is no driver input.

Comment: @jwh20 - https://www.makeuseof.com/what-is-steer-by-wire-technology/#:~:text=Steer%2Dby%2Dwire%20is%20still,%2C%20and%20Mercedes%2DAMG%20GT3. Nissan had installed it in an Infiniti model in 2017 (IIRC), but it was taken out over concerns ... not because it didn't work, but only because people like the idea of it.

Comment: I think you'll find info from manufacturer's service manuals. I think programming fail safes ensure against EPS taking over steering control from drivers.